# Set reference value in swift for CloudKit database

Tags: swift, reference, cloudkit

I'm trying to set some value for a record in my CloudKit database. I haven't problem to set any other kind of value on other fields like string or int but for Reference filedname(storyid) i get this error :

> "invalid attempt to set value type STRING for field 'storyid' for type
>   'Storypage', defined to be: REFERENCE"

```
func saveToCloud(note: String)
{

 let newpage = CKRecord (recordType: "Storypage")

 newpage.setValue(note, forKey: "pagecontent")

 newpage.setValue("UTENTE1", forKey:"username" )

 newpage.setValue("84EC8E60-1467-6411-5CDC-7E85DDB51C89", forKey: "storyid")

 database.save(newpage) { (record, error) in
 guard record != nil else {return}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

A reference field stores a [CKReference object](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cloudkit/ckrecord/reference), not a String:

> **Linking to Another Record**
>
> To link records together and create a strong
> relationship between them, create a new CKReference object, initialize
> it with the owner record, and assign that reference object to a field
> of the owned record. When you design the relationships among your own
> records, make the owner the more important of two related records.

So you'll want to get the recordID of the record you're relating newpage to, then use that to create a reference object, which you can then use to set the storyid field.